What is the correct way to add language syntax support with JetBrains Fleet?
Following the guide from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/textmate.html
And adding a Textmate bundle like https://github.com/Shopify/liquid-tmbundle into the mentioned directory which, for example, in MacOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Jetbrains/Fleet
There is still no syntax highlighting.
Adding the same bundles to other directories like $HOME/.fleet/textmate also does not work.
What is the correct way to add language syntax support with JetBrains Fleet?

Please follow the issue created for this case:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-29060/Custom-textmate-doesnt-work
Documentation will be fixed accordingly.
